# How to extract string between characters with multiple occurrences regex

Tags: regex, groovy

As an example I have the line:

```
if (ProPref.get("kcstcli","manageesw","on").equals("on")) {
```

I would like to extract:

```
"kcstcli","manageesw","on"
```

I tried the non greedy solutions but it doesn't work well ( I am using Groovy ).

```
it =~ /ProPref.get\((.*)?\)/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-greedy pattern is `.*?`, the `(.*)?` is an *optional* greedy subpattern that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of 0 or more characters other than a newline.

Use

```
it =~ /ProPref\.get\((.*?)\)/
```

Access the captured value via Group 1. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bE6xH2/2)

[Groovy sample code](https://ideone.com/8H0t6e):

```
s = "if (ProPref.get(\"kcstcli\",\"manageesw\",\"on\").equals(\"on\")) {"
regex = /ProPref\.get\((.*?)\)/

def m = s =~ regex
(0..<m.count).each { print m[it][1] + '\n' }
```

Result: `"kcstcli","manageesw","on"`